# Client authentication failure on Neo4J

Tags: spring-boot, docker, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j, java-17

I basically followed the steps described here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/neo4j/docs/current/reference/html/#configure-spring-boot-project

My application.properties contains the following:

```
spring.neo4j.uri=neo4j://localhost:7687
spring.neo4j.authentication.username=neo4j
spring.neo4j.authentication.password=verySecret357
```

I have a Neo4jConfiguration Bean which only specifies the TransactionManager, rest is (supposedly) taken care of by spring-boot-starter-data-neo4j:

```
@Configuration
public class Neo4jConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public ReactiveNeo4jTransactionManager reactiveTransactionManager(Driver driver,
                                                                      ReactiveDatabaseSelectionProvider databaseNameProvider) {
        return new ReactiveNeo4jTransactionManager(driver, databaseNameProvider);
    }

}
```

Neo4j (5.3.0) runs in a Docker container I started with

```
 docker run -d --name neo4j -p 7474:7474 -p 7687:7687 -e 'NEO4J_AUTH=neo4j/verySecret357' neo4j:4.4.11-community
```

I can access it through HTTP on my localhost:7474 and can authenticate using the credentials above.

Now, when I run my springboot app and try to create Nodes in Neo4j, I keep getting the same exception:

```
org.neo4j.driver.exceptions.AuthenticationException: The client is unauthorized due to authentication failure.
```

Running in debug, it however seems the client authentication scheme is correctly set:
[image: debug trace]

Any thoughts on what I might be doing wrong ?

Edit: one thing though, I would assume that the "authToken" would contain a base64-encoded String (username:password) as the scheme is basic auth. It looks like it's not the case (using neo4j-java-driver:5.2.0).

Edit: seems to be related to the Docker image. A standalone neo4j instance works fine.

Comment: Can you share your full docker command line?

Comment: I added it to the main question.

Comment: You are not using 5.3.0 but neo4j:4.4.11-community for Docker. This is not a problem because the 5.x Java driver will work also with 4.4. The credentials look good. Tried the same combination of versions and this _should_ work.
Just to be sure, you are running the application not within another docker container, right?

Comment: I actually tried various versions, I should have mentioned this (some in the 4.4.x range, and also the latest). The application is a springboot fat JAR running locally. One thing that may be causing this is the setup with WSL - altough I'm not running Docker from my Ubuntu subsystem, I know from experience that Docker/WSL/Windows can be troublesome from time to time. Will try on another environment later on.

Comment: Tried on MacOS Ventura 13.1 with Docker 20.10.22, using OpenJDK17 and neo4j 5.4.0-community : it runs smoothly. So WSL may be the issue...